# Check If Stage Skipped Salesforce Process Builder

Tags: opportunity, process-builder

I'm wondering if it is possible to detect if a stage was skipped using the salesforce process builder.

All of my stages are numbered 1 - 6, so for example I would want to detect if stage 1 was closed, then stage 3 was closed with stage 2 never being closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to query on OpportunityHistory records to find out whether a particular stage has been skipped or not.

Process builder does not support `Opportunity History` object for selection.